# Facebook Graph API for fetching the counts for User Posts, Friends, and Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to find the total counts for

1. User Posts
2. Friends
3. Likes

for the user and not for the pages that the user owns. I only need to have the counts, so I cannot add the permissions user_posts, user_friends, and user_likes.

Please note that, I'm currently using the Facebook Graph API v3.

Comment: The only one of those that a count is available for, is friends. But of course you won’t get that either, if you don’t get `user_friends` permission first.

Comment: No, wait, the summary with total count is available for the user’s liked pages as well (if that is what you’re after, your phrasing is ambiguous) - but again, no permission, no access.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. The main issue is that the facebook review team isn't letting me to use these permissions just to determine the counts. They want me to implement something which is beneficial to the facebook user who is allowing my app to share his/her data. I just want an alternate for all the mentioned permissions.

Comment: There is no alternate. If you don’t have an actual use case, where gathering that data benefits the user somehow, then there is no way for you to get it.

Comment: Actually the use case for the portal is simple. Just fetch the counts to determine how strong the user's profile is. That's all, and that is the main issue it seems. We are not doing anything beneficial to the users which seems reasonable to me.

Comment: _“to determine how strong the user's profile is”_ - for whom, for what purpose? _“We are not doing anything beneficial to the users which seems reasonable to me.”_ - Facebook protecting me from you getting your hands onto my data, in cases where it is not even beneficial to me - _that_ seems reasonable to me :-)

Comment: Well the purpose of finding whether the profile is strong or not, is to let the other users know how strong profile is someone having, and to follow him/her.

Comment: And I think you are right, I should have a detailed discussion with the facebook review team.